# Using native C Kiss_fft.c to calculate fft in android

Tags: android, c, makefile, java-native-interface, kissfft

My goal is to compile the kiss_fft libraries to use in JNI for android development.
However to begin with, I am attempting to just use the kiss_fft libraries on my linux machine in C.

when using Kiss_fft.c or Kiss_fftr.c from Kiss_fft ([Kissfft](http://kissfft.sourceforge.net/)
)to calculate the DFT. How exactly do you compile their libraries into your own file. In the top of my source C file, I #include kiss_fft.h and #include kiss_fftr.h, and also either place the kiss_fft souce code in my project root directory or in /usr/include/ in linux, then I compile with a makefile similar to this one:

```
#Makefile

#ARGS = -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror -O1
ARGS = -g -lsndfile -O1 -lm


FILES = spec_subv4.o kiss_fftr.o kiss_fft.o

spec_sub: $(FILES)
gcc $(ARGS) $(FILES) -o spec_sub  

spec_subv4.o:   spec_subv4.c 
gcc -lsndfile $(ARGS) -c spec_subv4.c -o spec_subv4

kiss_fftr.o:    kiss_fftr.c kiss_fftr.h kiss_fftr.h _kiss_fft_guts.h
gcc $(ARGS) -c kiss_fftr.c -o kiss_fftr

kiss_fft.o: kiss_fft.c _kiss_fft_guts.h
gcc $(ARGS) -c kiss_fftr.c -o kiss_fft
```

Looking through all the kiss_fft source files, I wrote this make file to build all the dependencies. However I still get

`undefined reference to kiss_fft`

`undefined reference to kiss_fft_alloc`

Which are internal functions of the kiss_fft libs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out, thanks for the input. I simply just compiled with:

```
gcc $@ -g -lsndfile -lm -std=gnu99 spec_sub_kiss.c kiss_fft.c kiss_fftr.c -o spec_sub_kiss
```

Where the -lsndfile is the libraries to read and write some .wav files for my project.

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile targets never actually compile kiss_fft.c

e.g.

```
kiss_fft.o: kiss_fft.c _kiss_fft_guts.h
gcc $(ARGS) -c kiss_fftr.c -o kiss_fft
```

compiles kiss_fftr.c not kiss_fft.c

Answer (score 1):

I think symbol/function kiss_fft, kiss_fft_alloc are not part of any libary included.

Few things must be checked before you link:

1. Check if symbols are available in library sndfile

   nm  | grep "kiss_fft"
2. Check if you have mentioned the PATH for library in make file.

   Include your library path as
   -L
3. Check if prototypes of these functions are in harder files

   Include them with
   -I
4. If any C,C++ combination code is used

   Use **extern "C"** sytax.
5. prototypes of functions must match with prototypes included in library.

Comment: Hmmm, well the kiss_fft() and kiss_fft_alloc() are both in kiss_fft.c, linked to by kiss_fft.h. When you say include library path -L do you mean something like:

gcc -L ../path-to-kiss_fft-headers-and-.c-files/

Comment: can you explain the use of the -l, so so far I have not compiled and lib files, '.so'.